# Force cURL to print 1 for failure, 0 for success?

Tags: perl, curl, nagios

I'm writing a Nagios plugin for a Mumble server in Perl (for the experience- plenty are already available), and I've already run into a brick wall. What I'd like to do is use `cURL` to  connect to the port Mumble binds itself to- if the connection is successful I'd like `cURL` to simply print a 0, and if it failed, it should print a 1. Looking through the man page I'm unable to find any flags that could replicate that sort of behavior. Any ideas? Could this be done in a more elegant way, or with a different utility?

Comment: You should use the [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) module for Perl rather than shelling out to a command-line utility.

Comment: I don't think I'd need LWP, since it'd just be making a request to localhost:64738, but it is entirely possible that would be the better option.

Comment: If you just want to check the TCP port, just establish a TCP connection. You don't need an HTTP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use IO::Socket and check to see if you can connect that way?  seems that that would be a touch more light weight than full on cURL.

Comment: From what I'm reading IO::Socket will probably be my best bet- thanks much!